# Label Without Proper Reference

Tags: tables, labels

I keep getting 'label without proper reference' and 'Reference 'tab1' on page 9 undefined'. Here is the code:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|P{7cm}|P{7cm}|}
            \hline
            \textbf{خفیف/\lr{Mild}}&\textbf{رایج/\lr{Common}}
            \\
            \hline
            \begin{itemize}
                \item بروز علائم بالینی خفیف که تصویربرداری در آن فایده‌ای ندارد.
            \end{itemize}
            & 
            \begin{itemize}
                \item پیدایش علائم و مشکلات تنفسی (ساختار پنومی – التهاب ریه) و تب
                \item امکان تصویربرداری در \lr{X-ray} و \lr{CT}
            \end{itemize}
            \\
            \hline
            \textbf{شدید/\lr{Severe}} & \textbf{بسیار شدید/\lr{Critically Severe}}
            \\
            \hline
            \begin{itemize}
                \item   ایجاد مشکلات تنفسی با :
                $ RR\geq30/\text{min} $
                \item   درصد اشباع اکسیژن در حالت عدم فعالیت :
                $ \textrm{Saturation Oxygen}\leq93\% $
                \item نسبت فشار اکسیژن شریانی (\text{PaO2}) به درصد اکسیژن تنفس عمیق بیمار (\lr{FiO2}):
                $ \frac{\text{PaO2}}{\text{FiO2}}\leq300\,\text{mmHg} $
            \end{itemize}
            &
            \begin{itemize}
                \item   نارسایی تنفسی و نیاز به دستگاه تهویه مکانیکی
                \item   شوک‌های عصبی    
                \item   اختلال در فعالیت بقیه اندام‌ها به طوری که بیماری نیاز به نظارت در \lr{ICU} دارد.
            \end{itemize}
            \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{طبقه بندی بالینی بیماران مبتلا به کوید 19 که توسط کمیسیون ملی سلامت چین منتشر شده است \cite{15}.}
    \end{center}
    \label{tab1}
\end{table}
```

I compile the code twice and it keeps happening. I have used

```
\ref{tab1}
```

and doubly checked that the string is exactly the same without success. Could you please point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Replace `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` with `\centering`. Place the `\centering` command in the line after `\begin{table}`

Comment: Put the `\label` command immediately after the `\caption`.

Comment: Unrelated you're probably not using the `\text` command right here. It is not meant to be used to "upright" text (it will be italic if the surrounding text is italic which is it what you want). Yu seem to be using it as units and chemical compounds, might be better to use the siunits and mhchem or chemmacros packages

Answer (score 2):

The label *must* be declared *after* the caption, as so:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            your amazing tabular
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{really amazing tabular}
        \label{tab1}
    \end{center}
    
\end{table}

the \ref{tab1} is really amazing (trust me!).
```

Thanks to @Peter Wilson in the comments.